# GoogleMap dont work PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, google-maps

I'd like someone to help me please. I have made a form inside of my html file just like

```
<form action="deneme.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="searchtxt" id="searchtxt" placeholder="Write something to search"></br>
            <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="locationbtn"  data-icon= "search" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-inline="true" value="Find Location"></button> 
            </div>
        </form>
```

when i have this and i click submit, my php file does not load the GoogleMap. When i have

```
<button href="#deneme.php" type="button" name="denemebtn"  data-icon= "search" onclick="location.href='deneme.php'" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">Find Location</button>
```

my map works but i cant take value of the searchtxt to use in my php file. Is there anyway to get searchtxt into my deneme file without `<form>` or is there any way to make googlemap work with `<input type="submit">`?

Thanks for your attention guys.

Comment: please have a try by alter `method="post"` with `method="get"`. I also don't understand `#deneme.php`. is it a php script or just a bookmark anchor?

Comment: I just put it not to have my button clicked look all the time, when i put it, i have my button normal theme all the time instead of clicked theme. I'll give a try for `method="get"´ tomorrow dude. will post here about if it works or not :)